# HTMLAgility Pack: Replacing content in a "mixed-type" node

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgility Pack to do some on-the-fly modification of HTML output -- finding all text nodes and replacing them:

```
const string xpath = "//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()[normalize-space(.) != '']";
var docNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath).ToList();
foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
{
    var parent = htmlNode.ParentNode;
    var newNode = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Text, doc, 0){InnerHTML = "Test"};
    parent.ReplaceChild(newNode, htmlNode);
}
```

But this seems to cause a problem if the textnode isn't the only child of the parent.  For example:

```
<label>Email:<br><input name="txtID" type="text" id="txtID" class="input"></label>
```

After being replaced, accessing doc.DocumentNode.OuterHTML results in the following exception:
Unable to cast object of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode'.

Am I doing the replacement incorrectly?  I can't really go and "clean up" all the original HTML documents that might run through this thing.

Answer (score 5):

It seems this is a problem with inconsistency between `HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType, HtmlDocument, int)` constructor you used and a way `InnerHtml` and `InnerText` methods work. `HtmlNode` constructor creates a node of type `HtmlNode` (but sets the type of the node to the value passed). When you want to get `InnerHtml` or `InnerText` of this node, AgilityPack performs something like this:

```
case HtmlNodeType.Text:
    html = ((HtmlTextNode)this).Text;
```

which actually causes an `InvalidCastException` you mentioned.

To avoid this I recommend to use another way of creating text nodes by using `HtmlDocument.CreateTextNode()` method:

```
foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
{
    var parent = htmlNode.ParentNode;
    var newNode = doc.CreateTextNode();
    newNode.InnerHtml = "Test";
    parent.ReplaceChild(newNode, htmlNode);
}
```

This will replace your text nodes correctly.